# define a rotation axis

Tags: animation

Can I define a rotation axis for a 3d object then set a rotation amount for animation?
I will duplicate the objects than set them at different orientations and all will rotate about the defined axis simultaneously at a certain angle amount and speed.

Comment: Maybe use an Empty and rotate around that? (I'm no animation expert, but that would be my first thought!)

Answer (score 1):

i would use a copy rotation constraint for that.

1. create an object, keyframe a rotation e.g. i keyframed z rotation at frame 1 and 60 with values 0 and 360, then in timeline press shift-E -> linear extrapolation to make it rotate forever

[image]

[image]

2. now copy that object, delete all keyframe and add "object constraint" copy rotation:

[image]

with these settings:

[image]

now you still can move and rotate that object as you like:

[image]

and then just copy this object as often as you like:

[image]